# Select Query from postgres with count

Tags: postgresql, select

I have two tables, one contains customers, the other one the bookings.
Now i want to see how many bookings come from one person but display it with their name instead of the id.

```
SELECT booking.id, COUNT(booking.id) AS idcount
FROM booking
GROUP BY booking.id ORDER BY idcount DESC;
```

The output is (correct count):

```
       id | idcount 
----------+--------
        2 |      8
        1 |      4
```

My attempt at getting the name displayed instead of the id was:

```
SELECT customer.lastn, customer.firstn, COUNT(booking.id) AS idcount
FROM booking, customer
GROUP BY customer.lastn, customer.firstn ORDER BY idcount DESC;
```

The output (wrong count):

```
 lastn    | firstn  | idcount 
----------+---------+--------
 Adam     | Michael |     13
 Jackson  | Leo     |     13
```

13 is the total number of bookings (i just cut the output off) so there's that coming from, however i cant make the transition to get the right count with the name.

Comment: why you are using cross join between booking and customer ? is booking.id equal to customer.id ?

Comment: Yes, the id in booking is one part of the primary key and equal to the customer id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a JOIN in your `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT customer.lastn, customer.firstn, COUNT(booking.id) AS idcount
FROM booking
    JOIN customer ON booking.id = customer.id
GROUP BY customer.lastn, customer.firstn 
ORDER BY idcount DESC;
```

The JOIN here tells how the `booking` table relates to your `customer` table.

Comment: Indeed, i tried JOIN but messed the syntax up, thanks

Comment: There might be possibility of having same last name and first name for two different customer. In that case it will sum those customer count.

Comment: @FahadAnjum agreed. @annoyedguy, to get around that you do a `GROUP BY customer.id, customer.lastnm, customer.firstn`

Comment: Thats luckily not the case yet but i guess that might save me some headache in the future!

Comment: @AnnoyedGuy Yes.